# Effective search in two-dimensional window

Tags: r

Consider a matrix specifying one two-dimensional region per line, and another matrix specifying point in a plane:

```
xmin <- c(3, 14, 25, 61)
xmax <- c(5, 18, 27, 65)
ymin <- c(33, 12, 83, 2)
ymax <- c(35, 16, 90, 6)
regions <- cbind(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

x <- c(7, 26, 4, 16)
y <- c(4, 85, 30, 13)
points <- cbind(x, y)
```

What is the fastest way of obtaining the indexes in `regions` that contains each of the points in `points`?

An example of what I want to achieve is:

```
apply(points, 1, function(x){
    which(regions[,'xmin'] < x[1] & regions[,'xmax'] > x[1] & regions[,'ymin'] < x[2] & regions[,'ymax'] > x[2])
})
```

But as the number of rows in both `regions` and `points` approach 1E5 this gets rather slow and I'm looking for a proper vectorized approach...

Thanks in advance...

best
Thomas

EDIT:

For anyone interested I made a function in C++ using Rcpp that provides roughly a 50x performance improvement. I'm not fluent in C++ so it could possibly be done better...

```
cppFunction('
    IntegerVector findInRegion(NumericVector x, NumericVector y, NumericVector xmin, NumericVector xmax, NumericVector ymin, NumericVector ymax){
        int pointSize = x.size();
        int regionSize = xmin.size();
        IntegerVector ans(pointSize);
        for(int i = 0; i < pointSize; i++){
            ans[i] = NA_INTEGER;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < pointSize; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < regionSize; j++){
                if(x[i] > xmin[j]){
                    if(x[i] < xmax[j]){
                        if(y[i] > ymin[j]){
                            if(y[i] < ymax[j]){
                                ans[i] = j+1;
                            };
                        };
                    };
                };
            };
        };
        return ans;
    }
')

findRegion <- function(points, regions){
    if(!all(c('x', 'y') %in% colnames(points))){
        stop('points must contain columns named \'x\' and \'y\'')
    }
    if(!all(c('xmin', 'xmax', 'ymin', 'ymax') %in% colnames(regions))){
        stop('regions must contain columns named \'xmin\', \'xmax\', \'ymin\' and \'ymax\'')
    }
    findInRegion(points[, 'x'], points[,'y'], regions[, 'xmin'], regions[, 'xmax'], regions[, 'ymin'], regions[, 'ymax'])
}
```

One drawback of this function is that it assumes a point can only belong to one region...

Comment: The fastest is probably to put the data in a database with spatial indices 
(I think SQLite can do that): the regions will then be stored into an efficient data structure
(an [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree)).

Comment: If there's anyone w/ access to the software which determines how to draw multiple overlaid windows in your average desktop GUI, this sure looks like the same problem.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd I like this idea, especially because R-trees seems tailored to these kind of problems (didn't know about them before). Have to do some testing on the overhead of constructing the database though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another solution, using an [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) index (a type of database index designed to store bounding boxes) with SQLite.
It turns out to be slightly slower than Simon's (7 seconds), probably because the data is copied to disk.

```
# Sample data: data.frames, rather than matrices
regions <- data.frame(id=1:length(xmin), xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
points  <- data.frame(x, y)

library(RSQLite)
con <- dbConnect("SQLite", dbname = "/tmp/a.sqlite") 
dbGetQuery( con, "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE regions USING rtree (id, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)" )
dbWriteTable( con, "regions", regions, row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE )
dbWriteTable( con, "points",  points, row.names = TRUE )
res <- dbGetQuery( con, "
  SELECT points.row_names, regions.id
  FROM   points, regions
  WHERE  xmin <= x AND x <= xmax
  AND    ymin <= y AND y <= ymax
" )
```

Comment: +1 I wonder if this solution would be better able to handle doing an even more massive dataset because it doesn't have to hold everything in memory all at once?

Answer (score 4):

This is a really interesting problem. I did some initial testing and this *seems* like it might be faster, but I really don't know how well it scales. I'd be interested if you could test on your real data and report some timings:

```
#  Are X coords greater than xmin
lx <- outer( points[,1] , regions[,1] , ">" )

#  Are X coords less than xmax
hx <- outer( points[,1] , regions[,2] , "<" )

#  Ditto for Y coords
ly <- outer( points[,2] , regions[,3] , ">" )
hy <- outer( points[,2] , regions[,4] , "<" )

#  These matrices for X and Y points have 1 if coords is in range, 0 otherwise
inx <- lx * hx
iny <- ly * hy

#  The final result matrix has 1 if both X and Y coords are in range and 0 if not
#  Rows are points, columns are regions
res <- inx * iny
```

On data of 100000 points and 100000 regions this approach won't work unless you have *alot* of RAM. However I think it's pretty useable if you divide the number of regions up into *chunks* of around 1000 each. On my desktop, 100,000 points and 1,000 regions took 5 seconds:

```
Unit: seconds
        expr      min      lq  median       uq      max neval
 eval(simon) 4.528942 4.55258 4.59848 4.607572 4.671511     5
```

As a rough guide to the magnitude of difference in timings I saw between your `apply` method and this one, with 10,000 points and 1,000 regions (based on 5 runs):

```
Unit: milliseconds
        expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
 eval(simon)  394.7165  402.0919  403.0491  404.6943  428.7077     5
    eval(OP) 1359.5889 1364.6308 1372.4980 1383.1327 1491.4628     5
```

And with 100,000 points and 1,000 regions (based on one run):

```
Unit: seconds
        expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
 eval(simon)  4.352857  4.352857  4.352857  4.352857  4.352857     1
    eval(OP) 14.027390 14.027390 14.027390 14.027390 14.027390     1
```

This is the code I used to generate sample data and to run the benchmark:

```
set.seed(4862)
xmin <- sample(25,1000,repl=T)
xmax <- xmin + sample(15,100,repl=T)
ymin <- sample(25,1000,repl=T)
ymax <- ymin + sample(15,1000,repl=T)
regions <- cbind(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

x <- sample(25,100000,repl=T)
y <- sample(25,100000,repl=T)
points <- cbind(x, y)


OP <- quote({ res <- apply(points, 1, function(x){
    which(regions[,'xmin'] < x[1] & regions[,'xmax'] > x[1] & regions[,'ymin'] < x[2] & regions[,'ymax'] > x[2])
}) })


simon <- quote({
lx <- outer( points[,1] , regions[,1] , ">" )
hx <- outer( points[,1] , regions[,2] , "<" )
ly <- outer( points[,2] , regions[,3] , ">" )
hy <- outer( points[,2] , regions[,4] , "<" )
inx <- lx * hx
iny <- ly * hy
res <- inx * iny })

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark( eval(simon) , eval(OP) , times = 1L )
```

I'd recommend doing this in chunks. HTH.

Comment: I should have mentioned this, but I actually attempted to vectorize this problem using outer. A real life example might constitute 1-2 million regions and 5000 coordinates. The memory-overhead of constructing such a matrix is way to big. For smaller sized problems it's a good solution though...

Comment: @ThomasP85 gosh that is a lot! Well, if you need fast iteration over long vectors you might consider implementing this in `Rcpp` if you have some C++ experience. These operations are quite simple and extremely serial.

Comment: This would be my last resort - I just wondered whether there was a native R way. I almost always learn something from seeing people propose optimized approaches in R :-)